# How to hide Git info about shared library from Jenkins job page?

Tags: git, jenkins

We use some shared Groovy-libraries and now every job info includes their git commit. We want to hide it, because you can mismatch it with project build information.

Example:

[image]

Screenshot with library configuration:

[image]

And I import library in pipelines with

```
@Library('common-lib@some-branch') _
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Jenkins 2.303.2, latest plugins as of 2021.*

1. Navigate to https://your.jenkins.com/configure
2. Uncheck `Include @Library changes in job recent changes` checkbox under "Global Pipeline Libraries"

[image]